# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 version generator

Tags: build, version

Is there any smart solution to auto number build version.

Every build should increment version number and store it somewhere in executable project, and read this number during program execute.

Im using VS 2008 - Project for mobile device with .NET CF 3.5

Answer (score 1):

In your AssemblyInfo.cs, simply have:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

(and no `AssemblyFileVersion`)

This will auto number the third and fourth parts of the version based on date and time - you can still adjust the major and minor builds to match up with your marketing team's idea of the version number...